# Scala algorithm for generating combinations list of certain length from two lists

Tags: algorithm, scala

I have a two Scala List[String]. This is Poker cards like:

```
list_1 = ("4cKs4h8s7s")
```

list with only one value from concat 5 card as: 4c, Ks, 4h, 8s, 7s. Card is a 2 character string with the first character representing the Values and the second character representing the Suits. 
Values: 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,T,J,Q,K,A 
Suits: c=Clubs, h=Hearts, s=Spades, d=Diamonds

AND

```
list_2 = ( "Ad4s", "Ac4d", "As9s", "KhKd", "5d6d",..."XxYy")
```

OR

```
list_2 = ( "Ad4sTd2s", "Ac4d5c6c", "As9s7d8d", "KhKdAsTs", "5d6d9c8c",..."WwXxYyZz")
```

any counts of 2 or 4 cards. Can be as concat two cards like Ac,4s (Ac4s) or 4 cards like Ad,4s,Td,2s(Ad4sTd2s)

I would like to get a list with all possible combination of 5 cards like: for example:

```
67 -> 12345
61234, 62345, 61245, 61345, 71234, 72345, 71345, 71245, 67123, 67234, 67345
```

the same with 4 cards:

```
6789 -> 12345
61234, 62345, 71234, 72345, 67123, 67234, 67345, 68123, 68234, 68345, .... ~ 35 combinations
```

Example with card:

```
Ad4s    
4cKs4h8s7s
list_res = ("Ad4cKs4h8s", "AdKs4h8s7s", "Ad4c4h8s7s", "AdKs4h8s7s", "4s4cKs4h8s", "4sKs4h8s7s", "4s4cKs8s7s", "4s4c4h8s7s", "Ad4s4cKs4h", "Ad4sKs4h8s", "Ad4s4h8s7s")
```

OR result can be list of lists as:

```
list_res = (("Ad","4c","Ks","4h","8s"), ("Ad","Ks","4h","8s","7s"), ("4s","4c","Ks","4h","8s"), ("4s","Ks","4h","8s"7s"), ("Ad","4s","4c","Ks","4h"), ("Ad","4s","Ks","4h","8s"), ("Ad","4s","4h","8s","7s"))
```

I should have a Scala algorithm for that generating these combinations. Could someone help me, please?

Comment: You are right. I missed it. Need to all possible combinations from 2 or 4 cards with 5 cards. UPDATED description

Comment: Note that there isn't really any such thing as a "Scala algorithm". The same algorithm can be expressed in multiple programming languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trivial answer is to combine the two lists and then get all the possible combinations of length `n`.

```
(lst1 ++ lst2).combinations(n)
```

But it looks like maybe you require at least one element from each list. (The question is far from clear.) In that case things get a bit more complicated.

```
val lstL = List('A','B')          //List of letters
val lstD = List('0','1','2','3')  //List of digits
val cl = 5                        //Length of each combination

Range(1,cl).flatMap{ x =>
  for {
    ls <- lstL.combinations(x)    if lstL.lengthIs >= x
    ns <- lstD.combinations(cl-x) if lstD.lengthIs >= cl-x
  } yield ls ++ ns
}
//res0: IndexedSeq[List[Char]] = Vector(List(A, 0, 1, 2, 3)
//                                    , List(B, 0, 1, 2, 3)
//                                    , List(A, B, 0, 1, 2)
//                                    , List(A, B, 0, 1, 3)
//                                    , List(A, B, 0, 2, 3)
//                                    , List(A, B, 1, 2, 3))
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. It works for me.

Comment: Dear **jwvh** Could you please have a look this my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59416303/scala-algorithm-for-executing-own-function-for-each-lists-of-vectors-of-list-and